# PHP dropdown select function to dynamically create months

Tags: php, date, select, drop-down-menu, monthcalendar

I keep having issues on the last day of the month, other than that this code works just fine to display all 12 months starting at the current month.  On the last day of the month I get duplicates of some months and others do not show at all.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
<select id="month" name="month">


<?php

//lists months

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; ++$i) 
        {
            $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
            $value = date('m', $time);
            $label = date('F', $time);

//if month is set stay on that month

            if($month==$value)
                { printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>' , $value, $label);
                }
            else
                {printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $value, $label);}
        }

?>

//first month shows instead of blank

    $("#target option:first")

</select>
```

Comment: where are you setting the value for $month ?

Comment: also, can you check if you are getting correct value for $time for different cases ?

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into an issue where from the current day X months later is skipping over a month. 
Instead of

```
   strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
```

Try using

```
    strtotime(sprintf('first day of +%d month', $i));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    function months($selctedMonth='january'){

        $months='<select name="month" size="1">';
        for ($i = 12; $i > 0; $i--) {
            $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d months', $i));   
            $label = date('F', $time); 
            $selctedM = strtolower($selctedMonth) == strtolower($label) ? 'selected' : '';
            $months.="<option value='$label'  $selctedM >$label</option>";
        }  
        $months.="</select>";
        return $months;
    }

     echo months(); 


?>
```

By default, January will be displayed as selected.

if you write  `<?php echo months('march'); ?>` then `march` will be selected by default.